# ¿Qué quiere decir "un rigor de cordonero"?

Tags: modismos

¿De dónde podría haber venido éste si es un modismo?

> Por último le prestó el dinero para instalar el taller de fotógrafo, que Jeremiah de Saint-Amour le pagó con **un rigor de cordonero**, hasta el último cuartillo, desde que retrató al primer niño asustado por el relámpago de magnesio.

Está sacado de "El amor en los tiempos del cólera" de Gabriel García Márquez.

Vocabulario necesario:

> [cordonero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ArjDlla), ra
>   1. m. y f. Persona que tiene por oficio hacer o vender cordones, flecos, etc.
>   2. m. Mar. Encargado de hacer jarcia.
>
> [cuartillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BTVrTUL)
>   (Entre otros:)
>   3. m. Cuarta parte de un real.
>   real de plata doble, o real de plata vieja
>
> [real de plata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VGqyuLj%7CVGtxgAo%7CVGuc9Wg)
>   1. m. Moneda de cambio, del valor de 16 cuartos. 32 reales de esta moneda componían el doblón de cambio, que era de 68 reales y 8 maravedís de vellón.

Comment: ¿Será que el desempeño del oficio de cordonero requiere mucho [rigor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WTWTstv), en el sentido de que hay que ser muy preciso?

Comment: @fedorqui Con los hilos finos o algo así? Debe ser.

Comment: @fedorqui Un cordonero y también la dicha deben ser muy oscuras porque ha resultado pocos referencias cuando busqué. http://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/un+rigor+de+cordonero

Comment: Yo apuesto por la propuesta de fedorqui. Viendo que el oficio de [cordonero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordonero) requiere esas herramientas, la tipología del trabajo, el hacer trenados o bordados con hilo de seda, de oro, trabajo con lentejuelas, etc... suena como un oficio en el que hay que poner mucha atención, paciencia, **rigor**, etc.

Comment: La novela es de 1985, pero en el _Diccionario de Autoridades_ (tomo C, 1729) se cita lo siguiente en la entrada de _cordonero_: "Y que los Sastres, Jubetéros, Calcetéros, Cordonéros y Sombreréros [...] que cortaren ò hicieren pública ò secretamente, qualquier ropa contra lo contenido y declarado en ella [...] incurran en quatro años de destierro". ¿Es o no es como para tener rigor?

Comment: @carlos alejo si, es otra interpretación de rigor, en lugar de parsimoniosamente, significa exposición a infortunios pero sabiendo el contexto yo, jeremiah es muy amigo suyo del doctor y creo que quería devolver el préstamo yo no veía la deuda como sufrimiento.

Comment: Por "la dicha" arriba quería decir el dicho. "Felicidad" no tendría sentido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el contexto que mencionas, la frase creo que es bastante clara: Jeremiah pidió un préstamo y luego lo devolvió. Al hablar de *con un rigor de cordonero* se está refiriendo a que la devolución fue extremadamente minuciosa, sin dejar de pagar ni un solo céntimo.

Actualmente la expresión que se suele usar para estos menesteres es *pagar religiosamente*:

> [**religiosamente**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VqJMNbI)
>   2. adv. Con puntualidad y exactitud.

Por qué usa García Márquez el símil del cordonero es una incógnita y todo parece indicar que es un modismo de largo alcance. Tal y como se mencionó en los comentarios, el [*cordonero*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ArjDlla) es una *Persona que tiene por oficio hacer o vender cordones, flecos, etc*. Tamaña labor requiere ser muy preciso, pues de lo contrario los cordones tendrían nudos, imprecisiones, etc. Por tanto, es fácil asumir que el rigor que se le pide sea alto. Por el mismo motivo podríamos hablar de *rigor de vidriero* o *rigor de cirujano* (si bien este último suele usarse para la precisión, íntimamente relacionada con rigor en según qué contextos).

Buscando en el [CORDE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2519/1674) he encontrado unas cuantas referencias a *cordonero* en textos de hace bastantes siglos. Al parecer, esta profesión debía ser bastante más común que ahora y, por ende, podía llegar a usarse para expresiones. Hoy en día no creo que esta labor exista.